# TypeError: The x variable is categorical, but one of ['numeric', 'datetime'] is required

Tags: typeerror

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
f = open('/Users/justkiddings/Desktop/Python/TKO/TKO.csv', ) # open the file

data = pd.read_csv(f) # read the .csv file
co=data['CO']
no2=data['NO2']  # set the data

sns.kdeplot(co,shade=True) # to make a figure of CO
sns.kdeplot(no2,shade=True) # to make a figure of NO2
plt.show()
```

why does it error and how to solve it?

```
runfile('/Users/justkiddings/Desktop/Python/Code/untitled18.py', wdir='/Users/justkiddings/Desktop/Python/Code')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/justkiddings/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "/Users/justkiddings/Desktop/Python/Code/untitled18.py", line 11, in <module>
    sns.kdeplot(co,shade=True) # to make a figure of CO

  File "/Users/justkiddings/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py", line 46, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)

  File "/Users/justkiddings/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py", line 1762, in kdeplot
    p._attach(ax, allowed_types=["numeric", "datetime"], log_scale=log_scale)

  File "/Users/justkiddings/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/_core.py", line 1125, in _attach
    raise TypeError(err)

TypeError: The x variable is categorical, but one of ['numeric', 'datetime'] is required
```

Data:

DATE,HOUR,STATION,CO,FSP,NO2,NOX,O3,RSP,SO2

1/1/2022,1,TSEUNG KWAN O,67,29,17,18,125,47,4

1/1/2022,2,TSEUNG KWAN O,68,31,18,18,119,50,5

1/1/2022,3,TSEUNG KWAN O,67,35,16,16,116,47,5

1/1/2022,4,TSEUNG KWAN O,66,30,14,15,112,46,4

1/1/2022,5,TSEUNG KWAN O,67,25,14,14,102,47,4